# Vertical spike like water drop

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Slow motion guys created this  [Energy Spike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWKFPTgkpXo) ( at 1 min 53 sec ) that looks like a massive water drop or like a negative vortex  in the Edinburgh Hydraulics laboratory.

[image: Slow Mo Pic]
Using momentum of radial inward energy and equation of continuity/energy is it possible to formulate and calculate to solve for this instantaneous shape?

Comment: What do you mean by 'momentum of radial inward energy'?

Comment: I imagined that all energy is directed to circle center by wave making paddles. Water has zero resultant in the horizontal plane and so has to rise against gravity in the available degree of freedom with conserved energy.